# Babel craching after saving any changes (Cannot find module './transform-classic')

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs, babel-loader

I updated my dependencies and now when I update any file in any way, I get the bellow error:

[image: Error Log]

Any idea what I can do in this situation?

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue and found this: @babel/preset-react

run `npm install --save-dev @babel/preset-react`

babel source I got this from: https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-react